# How to negate conjunction of two attributes in CSS selector

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I wonder how to build a CSS selector to match element that do not have two given attributes at the same time. I tried

```
tagName:not([attra][attrb])
```

As I want all `tagName`s that does `:not` have `[attra]` **and** `[attrb]` **at the same time**.

Unfortunately Firefox, and Chrome (stable and Canary) says that

```
'tagName:not([attra][attrb])' is not a valid selector.
```

While `tagName[attra][attrb]`, `tagName:not([attra]):not([attrb])` are valid, but naturally does not return what I want.

Comment: Why does `tagName:not([attra]):not([attrb])` not return what you want?

Comment: From the other answers that's an `AND` scenario and the `,` makes it an `OR` which I guess is what he's looking for.

Comment: @chopper because that does not select elements with just `attra` or `attrb` and not both.

Comment: Ah yeah makes sense. The answers below look good

Comment: @chopper: Don't forget to upvote them.

Comment: The question is unclear; from the comments, but not from the question directly, it seems that the selector should match any element in class A or in class B but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using multiple selectors seems to do the trick.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/4V3y5/

```
document.querySelectorAll("p:not([attra]),p:not([attrb])");
```

---

First pass selects all `p` elements without `attra`, which will exclude the ones with both.

Second pass selects all `p` elements without `attrb`, which again, excludes the ones with both.

Comment: That's exact result that I need. Could you also explain why `p:not([attra][attrb])` is not valid?

Comment: @tomalec: Because `:not()` only accepts a single, simple selector. No combinations. So even `div.some_class` doesn't work, but just `.some_class` would.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible with a single `:not()` statement, using multiple selectors is fine though:

`div:not([attra]):not([attrb]), div[attra]:not([attrb]), div[attrb]:not([attra])`

**Equates to**: div without `attra` or `attrb`, div with attribute `attra` but not `attrb` or div with attribute `attrb` but not `attra`.

This will get a lot more verbose very quickly if you need to use more than two attributes.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/e67uN/2/

Comment: What I need is selector that matches elements that `are tagName & !( has attra & has attrb)`, your proposition returns `are tagName & has attra & !has attrb | are tagName & has attrb & !has attra`.

Comment: @tomalec then you simply add `div, ` to the start.

Comment: I think what he's getting at is that you're excluding elements that have neither `attra` nor `attrb`.

Comment: @cookiemonster My comment was supposed to fix that but I was a bit rash... I updated my answer with a working fix.